# Questão Teórica - Thread Bloqueada é encerrada

Tags: thread, sistema-operacional

O que pode acontecer em termos de falhas quando uma *thread* que está bloqueada, fez *I/O* ou está em um *mutex* por exemplo, é encerrada?

Só encontro questões práticas de como encerrar um *thread* bloqueada.